# What does scalar mean in an ARM instruction?

Tags: arm

Does scalar mean an instruction works directly with floating points?  I get that if you use vectors you use two or more objects but what about scalar?  A lot of the instructions say scalar and they describe the inputs and outputs as floating point values.

Like this one:
FADD (scalar)
This instruction adds the floating-point values of the two source SIMD&FP registers, and writes the result to the destination SIMD&FP register.

It says scalar but I assume it means floating point...

Comment: scalar is just single value, in the sense it is not array/matrix/string/object, it can be byte, integer, or float

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A scalar processor acts on one piece of data at a time. A vector processor acts on several pieces of data with a single instruction. A superscalar processor issues several instructions at a time, each of which operates on one piece of data. ARM pipelined processor is a scalar processor.

[Scalar Processor Articles](https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/computer-science/scalar-processor)

Comment: Thanks! So a vector could be many things?  Like an array?

Comment: vector processor is an array processor, yes